# Primary key addition for a table which contatins no data is too slow

Tags: mysql, performance, primary-key

We are using mysql. We are running 10 alter queries which contains 3 Primary key deletion and 4 column addition and 3 primary key addition. And this alter query is on three tables which don't contain any data. To run this query system took 15s. Usually system wont take this much for alter query. But for a table which contains no data I am not sure why it is taking this much of time.

I am not sure whether it is because of primary key addition and deletion or any mysql configuration is wrong or because of the machine.

While this migration alone system is slow. After and before the migration is system is behaving as normal.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Below are the queries. I was running three sets like this.

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 DROP PRIMARY KEY; 

ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD Column3 INT(10) DEFAULT ‘1'; 

ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD PRIMARY KEY Table_PK(Column1, Column2 , Column3 );
```

Comment: Were the tables just created or they had had lots of rows before but they were deleted/truncated?

Comment: Are the tables MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Is the issue repeatable with the same original structure and alters (on a test server preferably)?

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ It was created a while back but from it is created it doesn't have any data at all and tables are in InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You are running in Windows, correct?  Perhaps an older version of Windows and an older version of MySQL?  File operations are slow.  `ALTER TABLE`, especially when changing the `PRIMARY KEY`, requires creating 1-3 files, copying over some stuff (not much in your case), removing the old 1-3 files, then renaming the files.

`ALTER` on an empty table is not a priority.  However, some improvements were made in 5.6 on Windows.  Still, I suggest that Windows file management is the main culprit. Your code may have added up to 27 system calls for file manipulation.  15 seconds seems about right for Windows.

You could speed the process up by combining the statements:

```
ALTER TABLE Table1
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD Column3 INT(10) DEFAULT '1',    -- (I fixed the syntax error here)
    ADD PRIMARY KEY Table_PK(Column1, Column2 , Column3 );
```

With few exceptions, you can combine multiple `ALTERs` for a single table into a single `ALTER`.  And, unless all can be run with `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`, it is faster to combine them.

Consider using `INT UNSIGNED` for `Column3`.  And/or some smaller type of `INT`, such as `SMALLINT`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually we are using linux and mysql version -5.5.21 . And things i don't get it was,1.)  If alter query for deleting and adding primary key is more costly than other alter queries. because we were running 10 column addition regularly and that has no impact on system. Yesterday while adding and deleting PKs some of the other queries were executing slowly because of this. We were not sure whether is system is getting slow because of this PK addition alter query or because of some machine problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 5.5 virtually all `ALTERs` rebuild the table.  So, combining multiple actions into a single `ALTER` is almost always faster than one by one.

Comment: In normal production systems, `ALTER` is "never" used.  What are you doing "regularly"?  Perhaps the tables need to be restructured so you "never" need to add a column?

Comment: Thanks. So you are saying multiple actions in a single Alter query is fast. Thanks for the tip will try to add that. And yes, in production system for new features like that we will have to add columns like twice a month.  Can you explain me on this "Perhaps the tables need to be restructured so you "never" need to add a column?"

Comment: "Twice a month" -- high, but not terrible.  "Restructure" -- I was thinking of entities like things for sale, where new "attributes" (color, size, focal length, wheelbase, ...) keep showing up and you add new items.  Having all of them as columns is "bad" design.

Comment: For 5.5, combine your `ALTERs`.  But keep in mind that when you upgrade to 5.6 or later, `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` is _much_ faster, but has restrictions to be aware of.

Comment: Thanks ll keep in mind. Only thing now i am having doubt is alter query for adding PK is costlier than other alter queries.

Comment: Adding the PK (or changing the PK by `DROPping` and `ADDing` it) for InnoDB (not MyISAM) involves rearranging the data to be in PK order.  Hence, it will usually be slower than most other `ALTERs`.  Other alters can "tag along for free" -- adding/modifying column(s), for example, are "free" when copying each row to put it where the new PK wants it to be.

Comment: Thanks Rick James. That clear the things. now the last thing is since the table doesn't have any data at all i assume there is no need of rearranging of data isn't it? Since this alter query took 2s to complete, is this time really needed even for an empty table???

Comment: Now we are back to the issue of OS file manipulation.

Comment: oh for that you are saying thats due to linux OS file manipulation. Thanks Rick for you nice explanations.